# Using babel with preset-env on a small node project, unable to convert import/export statements to commonjs

Tags: node.js, babeljs, commonjs

I'm trying to set up a node project so I can use the common import/export syntax, and for compatibility, use babeljs to convert the `import` and `export` statements to `require`s.

When I try transpiling using babel though, I'm not seeing any changes and I don't know why.

Here's my `babel.config.js`

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  // I thought this was what I would need to add for making the changes, based on the docs
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"],


  // env takes care of the majority of changes I might need to convert code to make
  // easy to run on a wider range of machines
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          // target an older version where I know there is no ESM support
          node: "10"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  // this was in the docs too - I'm not sure if  I need it TBH
  sourceType: "module"
}
```

I have a bunch of code using `import/export`, and `async/await` in a directory, that I wanted to transpile and put into another directory, `lib`.

Here's the command I am using:

```
npx babel src --out-dir lib
```

My package.json file online too, and there's nothing too esoteric there. I've tried to follow the documentation faithfully.

I would expect to see changes in the code to replace the import/export calls with requires in the lib, but no joy.

What am I doing wrong here? I worked on a related project 6-7 months ago, where I am using babel like this and it *does* make the changes for me.

You can see the [branch with the problem code on github](https://github.com/thegreenwebfoundation/grid-intensity/tree/ca-fixing-preset-support), with the [package.json](https://github.com/thegreenwebfoundation/grid-intensity/blob/main/package.json), and [here's the source code for other project mentioned where it *is* working](https://github.com/thegreenwebfoundation/greentrace-lib).

Please be gentle, fellow SO commenters - I'm trying my best, I really am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using `"babel-cli": "^6.26.0"` instead of `"@babel/cli": "^7.11.6"` that should fix it.